# myView.setLayoutParams(otherView.getLayoutParams()); Not working, why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Got my TextView in the xml:

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="TextView"/>
```

I want to create multiple TextViews but i want to look them the same as **this**.

So I tried:

```
TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);

newTextView.setLayoutParams(myTextView.getLayoutParams());
```

I think this should get all the layout parameters from myTextView straigthlghly(?) from the xml, and pass them to newTextView to set them.

My problem is: Nothing happens. It does not take effect, why?

Comment: do both of the views are inside the same type of layout (i assume linearLayout) ? i think that only if that's correct , you will be able to do this operation.

Comment: They are in the same linearLayout, so yeah, they parents are the same.

Comment: check my answer. i've tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a sample project which shows that it works.
you can see that it works by looking at the preview of the visual editor , which looks different than what is shown at runtime.
i think that your mistake was that you didn't set 0px (or 0dp, zero is still zero) for the weighted views.

main.xml (layout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/container">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0px" android:text="TextView1"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#ffff0000" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView2"
    android:background="#ff00ff00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TestActivity.java :

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
  {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final LayoutParams layoutParams=tv1.getLayoutParams();
    tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    // adding textView programatically:
    final TextView tv3=new TextView(this);
    tv3.setText("textView3");
    tv3.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
    tv3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    final ViewGroup root=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
    root.addView(tv3);
    }
  }
```

Comment: He's trying to create the views in the program, so using `findViewById` is not going to work for him other than for finding the first one that is in the xml.

Comment: it's just an example , of course he can replace it with the creation of a new view. anyway, i will soon update it to include it too.